# Currency Type is not showing up on my Visual Force Page

Tags: multi-currency, force, visual

Multi Currency is turned on in my org.  I have a Visual Force Page with a Currency Field on it but the Currency type is not showing.  The page needs to show if the amount is in GBP, USA, HKD, AUS etc.  Here is the code:

```
<td class="label" style="padding-left: 4px;">
{!$Label.PO_Total}
</td> 
<td class="label" style="text-align:right;">
{!ROUND(Purchase_Order__c.Total__c, 2)}
</td>
```

Purchase_Order__c.Total__c is the field.  Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show the currency I believe you have to use and output field

```
<apex:outPutField value="{!Purchase_Order__c.Total__c}"/>
```

Comment: @MaryClevidence - Glad it worked for you. Since you are new, when a question you ask gets answered it is best to accept the correct answer by checking the check box to accept it. This allows other with similar questions to find answers and keeps the question from surfacing as unanswered.